# Create named routes for OmniAuth in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, omniauth

After having watched Ryan's excellent Railcast [Simple OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth), I've managed to implement authentication in my app.

Everything is working fine, but in my view I have links that look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Twitter', '/signin/twitter' %>
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Facebook', '/signin/facebook' %>
```

I was wondering if there is an elegant way to create a named route to replace that with:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Twitter', signin_twitter_path %>
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Facebook', signin_facebook_path %>
```

or:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Twitter', signin_path(:twitter) %>
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Facebook', signin_path(:facebook) %>
```

OmniAuth already handles those routes... In my `routes.rb` file I only have stuff for callbacks and signing out:

```
match '/signin/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
match '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :signout
```

So I don't know where I could create those named routes.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notice that in link_to, you're just providing a string for the route argument. So you can just define a method in a helpers file.

```
# application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def signin_path(provider)
    "/auth/#{provider.to_s}"
  end
end

# view file
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Twitter', signin_path(:twitter) %>
```

If you want to get all meta

```
# application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    if /^signin_with_(\S*)$/.match(name.to_s)
      "/auth/#{$1}"
    else
     super
    end
  end
end

#view file
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Twitter', signin_with_twitter %>
```

Comment: How does this work with an application deployed to a Sub-URI?

Comment: How would you handle additional parameters? (e.g. the 'origin'-parameter). Ideally signin_path would accept all parameters a regular *_path method would.

Comment: Also, how would you make this method available to controllers?

Comment: Although, it is an old answer and comments, but for the sake of completeness [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13613223/673826) answers about controllers as well.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `routes.rb`

`get "/auth/:provider", to: lambda{ |env| [404, {}, ["Not Found"]] }, as: :oauth`

Now you can use `oauth_path` url helper to generate urls.

Eg. `oauth_path(:facebook) # => /auth/facebook`

Answer (score -6):

With Rails 3 you can do :

```
# routes.rb
match '/signin/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create', :as => :signing

#view.erb
<%= link_to 'twitter', signing_path(:provider => 'twitter') %>
<%= link_to 'facebook', signing_path(:provider => 'facebook') %>
```

Comment: This will incorrectly create a link to the *callback* URL, instead of the OmniAuth redirect URL of '/auth/:provider'.