# rails omniauth, routes, link_to, and base_uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, omniauth

I've started using omniauth in a project but having some issues in production vs. development.  In production my RailsURI is /myApp and in development it's just /

In my templates I use <%= link_to "/auth/google" do %> which works for production but not development since I need to link to "/myApp/auth/google".  My route look like this:

match '/auth/:service/callback' => 'services#create'

Ideally, I'd like to have some setup like:
<%= link_to provider_google_path %> generated for me for each provider I support.  I guess I could support this by putting in a helper like <%= link_to provider(:google) %> but was wondering if there was a best practices way of solving this.

Comment: So, how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a similar question here that has an answer. You may want to take a look at that.

[Create named routes for OmniAuth in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361994/create-named-routes-for-omniauth-in-rails-3)