# Where to put Ruby helper methods for Rails controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, view-helpers

I have some Ruby methods certain (or all) controllers need. I tried putting them in `/app/helpers/application_helper.rb`. I've used that for methods to be used in views. But controllers don't see those methods. Is there another place I should put them or do I need to access those helper methods differently?

Using latest stable Rails.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You should define the method inside `ApplicationController`.

Comment: He will also have to add `helper_method :my_helper_method` in `ApplicationController` to make them available to the views.

Comment: wont this lead to a fat controller over time?

Comment: also @David that violates MVC

Answer (score 76):

For Rails 4 onwards, concerns are the way to go. There was a decent article which can still be [viewed](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324181905/http://richonrails.com/articles/rails-4-code-concerns-in-active-record-models) via the Wayback Machine.

In essence, if you look in your controllers folder you should see a concerns sub-folder. Create a module in there along these lines

```
module EventsHelper
  def do_something
  end
end
```

Then, in the controller just include it

```
class BadgeController < ApplicationController
  include EventsHelper

  ...
end
```

Comment: I find this the nicest solution when you don't need the helper methods included in all your controllers. This solution also applies to models.

Comment: Nice. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you know if we need to use `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` with controller concerns?

Comment: No need to do extend ActiveSupport::Concern inside controller/concerns directory. You just need to define modules above directory and can simply do include as mentioned above(for rails 4.2 and rails 5).

Comment: probably the best answer

Comment: Can this method be accessed from View?

Answer (score 30):

you should define methods inside application controller, if you have few methods then you can do as follow

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
  helper_method :first_method
  helper_method :second_method

  def first_method
    ... #your code
  end

  def second_method
    ... #your code
  end
end
```

You can also include helper files as follow

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  include OneHelper
  include TwoHelper
end
```

Comment: is there a way to assign all the helper_methods on one line?

Comment: @HarshaMV I think you can just go ahead like `helper_method :first_method, :second_method`.

Answer (score 21):

You can call any helper methods from a controller using the `view_context`, e.g.

```
view_context.my_helper_method
```

Comment: There's a more modern version of this answer for Rails 5+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161692/12484

Answer (score 8):

Ryan Bigg response is good.

Other possible solution is add helpers to your controller:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  include OneHelper
  include TwoHelper
 end
```

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Including helpers in controller will end-up exposing helper methods as actions!

```
# With new rails (>= 5) 

helpers.my_helper_method


# For console

helper.my_helper_method
```